# Issue with Group-Concat and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to take this query:

```
SELECT
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
GROUP BY events.ID
```

Which works fine, and I made this one:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$data2 = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    events.SHORT_EVENT_DESC,
    events.SMALL_POSTER_URL,
    events.start_datetime,
    events.VENUE_LOCATION
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM 
    venues
INNER JOIN events
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID 
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
WHERE
    events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
AND
    WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND 
    venues.id = ".$id."
GROUP BY events.start_datetime) or die(mysql_error());
```

Which gives me two errors:

*First is with the Group Concat:*

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
>   FROM venues IN'

I understand I'm retrieving data primarily from the `venues` table, but does it matter when I'm joining the `events` table?

*And the second is with the `Group by` I have:*

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

I thought I closed off all strings so I'm not sure why it does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comma missing before `GROUP_CONCAT`, that's all!

**Edit:**

The second one is a typo also: There is a quote missing in the last line,

```
GROUP BY events.start_datetime) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
GROUP BY events.start_datetime") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't know how I could have missed it.